# query to find indexes affected by locales upgrade does not work

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

While upgrading a system from Debian stretch to Debian buster, I got a warning about collation changes with a link to https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes the database is currently running postgresql 9.6 from Debian stretch.

That page tells me I can find out which indexes in my database are affected by using the query

```
SELECT 
    indrelid::regclass::text, 
    indexrelid::regclass::text, 
    collname, 
    pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid) 
FROM 
    (SELECT indexrelid, 
            indrelid, 
            indcollation[i] coll 
     FROM 
            pg_index, generate_subscripts(indcollation, 1) g(i)) s 
JOIN 
    pg_collation c ON coll=c.oid
WHERE 
    collprovider IN ('d', 'c') 
    AND collname NOT IN ('C', 'POSIX');
```

However when I connect to my database and run the query I get.

> ERROR:  column "collprovider" does not exist
> LINE 4: WHERE collprovider IN ('d', 'c') AND collname NOT IN ('C', '...

How can I find out what if-any indexes in my databases are affected?

Comment: There is no `collprovider` in pg_collation for version 9.6. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/catalog-pg-collation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer in #postgresql on irc.

> <Myon> PostgreSQL too old for that query
> <Myon> just remove "collprovider and"

After removing "collprovider IN ('d', 'c') AND" from the query it ran successfully.